# why does gcc unexpectedly strip __attribute__(__packed__)?

Tags: gcc

Is there a reason why the pre-processor strips out attributes when
-U__GNUC__ is specified and there is at least 1 #include directive?
This seems like surprising behaviour to me. Here's an example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <limits.h>

struct S {
       int a;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
$ gcc -E -U__GNUC__ foo.c | tail -3
struct S {
       int a;
} ;
```

But if I remove the #include directive (or if I drop -U__GNUC__) then
attributes don't get stripped by the pre-processor which is what I
expect to happen.

```
$ cat foo2.c
struct S {
       int a;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
$ gcc -U__GNUC__ -E foo2.c
# 1 "foo2.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "foo2.c"

struct S {
        int a;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

Is this a gcc bug or is there documentation of this behaviour?

Comment: What if you use normal `gcc` instead of that `egcc`?

Comment: I edited to show gcc (egcc is just the name for gcc 4.9.2 on OpenBSD since gcc is the command for gcc 4.2.1 in base. I tested both versions as well as a gcc on Linux and all showed the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my platform standard headers indirectly include `/usr/include/argp.h`. And in `argp.h` it says

```
#ifndef __attribute__
/* This feature is available in gcc versions 2.5 and later.  */
# if __GNUC__ < 2 || (__GNUC__ == 2 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5) || __STRICT_ANSI__
#  define __attribute__(Spec) /* empty */
# endif
...
#endif
```

I.e. for low values of `__GNUC__` and for `__STRICT_ANSI__` modes `__attribute__` is pre-defined as an empty macro. By undefing `__GNUC__` you made it act like `0` in `#if` contexts. So, the above code turned `__attribute__` into an empty macro.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, but I'm OpenBSD. There's no /usr/include/argp.h. Is there a way to find if there's something similar on OpenBSD?

Comment: @ user267506: Take a look at your full `gcc` output (i.e. without `tail -3`) and see what library headers it includes and from where. Go to that location and grep there for `__attribute__`. This is how I found the above `argp.h` on RedHat.

Comment: thanks, you hit the nail on the head! /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h is the file with the same code on OpenBSD.